Australian movie about a false kidnapping and ensuing police stand off
Trying to identify a movie which I saw sometime around 1996 and I assume it was made mid 90s as I think we hired it from the video shop at the time.
I believe it was an Australian film. The basic plot is that a guy is holed up in a house somewhere with a girl (who I think he knows already), and for some reason it gets reported as a kidnapping even though if I remember correctly they are friends and she is there of her own free will. 
There ends up being a big stand off with the police surrounding the house, and a bunch of people come and camp nearby to watch what's happening.
At one point his dog gets shot by the police. 
He ends up surrendering and making some deal that he has to go off and join the army. In the end credits it's revealed that he got out of the army because he couldn't read.
Sorry that the details are a bit hazy, it was a long time ago!

Sounds like the Australian comedy Mr. Reliable (AKA My Entire Life) from 1996.

All Wally Mellish, an ex-convict in 1960s Australia, wants to do is live a quiet life with his girlfriend Beryl. Unfortunately when two police officers come around to disturb this, a misunderstanding quickly becomes out of control, resulting Wally, Beryl and her child being trapped in their house, surrounded by armed police under the impression that Wally is holding everyone hostage. Events quickly spiral into a media circus as, through the siege, Wally - inadvertently - manages to become a symbol for the anti-war movement. 

They indeed shoot his pooch. :( The film was based on a true story.


Thank you so much! I've been trying to find it for years.
